# Session variables being overwritten

Tags: php, session

I've built an environment where there are a few domains that (if you join and login) you end up iframe'ing onto one central domain.

eg:

> domain1.com -> join/login -> centraldomain.com
>   domain2.com -> join/login -> centraldomain.com
>   domain3.com -> join/login -> centraldomain.com
>   domain4.com -> join/login -> centraldomain.com

The only issues I'm having is the `$_SESSION` on centraldomain.com is overwritten by each domain that logs in - eg: in the session is the originating domain name.

Is there a way to get a unique number/string for each different connection that persists on the server or php that could be used to prefix `$_SESSION` variables so I can separate the different originating domains with differently names `$_SESSION` vars?

Or another concept around this?

Comment: how about a multidimensional array using the domain name as the key

Comment: maybe you could use `session_id()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). Using this function you may be able to set the scope of $_SESSION variables in a domain-wide basis:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'centraldomain.com');
```

or

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'domain1.com');
```